# how to write a script that will run commands after su, without using -c

Tags: sudo, su

I'm trying to automate a standard activity on a system I do not have root access on.  The administrator of the systems have given me authority to run `sudo su - 'user'` command, and *only* that command.  I can not add a `-c` argument or `sudo` will fail.

My script will have to start with my permissions, and midway through change to running with the user's permissions.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to make a script do this for me in a single command?

Before anyone asks, trying to get my `visudo` permissions extended is quite difficult.  While I could probably `su` using the password I do not know the password of the user, don't want to change it, and really should hardcode it in my script anyways, so regular `su` without `sudo` isn't really an option.  It seems like there has to be some way to work with the command I'm authorized to use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the commands that you want to run as the other user into a separate file,
`user2commands`, and then do

```
sudo su - user < user2commands
```

If you don’t want to have a separate file, consider:

```
sudo su - user << EOF
    commands to be run as the other user
        ︙
EOF
```

Comment: this has weird behavior if the commands need to interact with standard input. For example, if you use `cat` this won't work (e.g., try `echo cat | sudo su - user`)

Comment: How to escape the `<` character when we are putting the entire sudo command within an argument, inside an xml file. I am using phing, so I want to do something like this - `<exec command="sudo su auto_deploy << EOF
      echo 'Logged in user'
      whoami
      EOF" dir="${dir.scratchpad}" />`. The `<<` before the EOF is throwing XML validation error.